# In some way to calculate the number of entries in tags?

Tags: php, mysql, count, tags

**tags:**

```
id, name
---------
1   tag1
2   tag2
3   tag3 
4   tag4
```

**tags_id:**

```
id_tags, id_post
--------------
1          1    
2          3    
3          1   
4          2
```

how to as to count how many posts tags?

I need a mysql query..

I have a problem with that and I'm a beginner

Comment: show us what you have done

Comment: Give us your expected result for your sample data please.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id_tags, count(id_post) as id_post_count 
FROM tags_id 
GROUP BY id_tags
```

Comment: thanks :)
how to display posts from the most to the least with name tags?

Answer (score 0):

See @gontrollez for an answer about getting "How many posts are there per tag".

To answer "How many tags every post has", see:

```
SELECT id_post, COUNT(id_tags) AS id_tags_per_post_count 
FROM tags_id 
GROUP BY id_post
ORDER BY 2, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT tags_id.id_tags, tags.name, COUNT(id_post) AS post_count 
FROM tags_id
INNER JOIN tags ON tags_id.id_tags = tags.id
GROUP BY tags_id.id_tags
ORDER BY post_count DESC
```